# UIScrollView or UIImageView?

Tags: ios, image, uiscrollview, scroll, zooming

I need to place a photo in the screen and it should be able to be scrolled or zoomed,

I know UIScrollView does these, so I alloced one, but how about my photo?

I guess I should not just set the photo as the backgroundColor of my UIScrollView, and I haven't found any property of UIScrollView, in the document, to hold an image, such as "imageView", "contentView", or something like that.

So, what should I do to make a picture in my screen and make it able to respond to finger touches?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: add an UIImageView as subView in UiScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the UIImageView to the UIScrollView and set the min/max scale value to it.

Then implement the following UIScrollViewDelegate function.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
    return yourImageView;
}
```

If you want to have multiple items scaled, add all the view into a UIView, and put that UIView inside the UIScrollView. Of course you have to change the return view to that UIView in the above function.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your `UIImageView` as a subview of the `UIScrollView`. Also, set the scroll view's `contentSize` property to be equal to the size of the image view's `frame`.

Comment: Why should the scroll view`s `contentSize` be bigger than the size of the content it's going to display?

Comment: because if you set equal, then image will not scroll?

Comment: You're thinking of the **size** of the scroll view. You want the **size** of the scrollview to be bigger than the size of the content that you display in it. The `contentSize` should be equal to the size of the subview.

Comment: Okay, well you should probably go tell whoever wrote this [tutorial](http://awurl.com/9s8cXAldM) that they made a mistake. And while you're at it, you should let Apple know they need to fix their [Scroll View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html).

Answer (score 0):

THe scrollView is the first step.
Then you should add a UIImageView and load an image inside.
You need also to set the max e min zoomScale properties of the scrollview
And you must implement the scrollview delegate method `– viewForZoomingInScrollView:`